# VueJS - How to keep UserID's after fetching from API for deleting, editing user?

Tags: vue.js, dom

I have a listing for users like that. But i need to delete user when admin clicks the button. What do you offer for this situtation?

```
<div v-if="users.length" class="users">
    <section class="user" v-for="user in users" :key="user">
        <section>{{user.title}}</section>
        <section>{{user.username}}</section>
        <section><button onClick="DeleteUser()">Delete</button></section>
    </section>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose that your user object has prop `id`, so you can pass that id to @click handler method.

```
<button @click="deleteUser(user.id)">Delete</button>
```